# Prevent a user to spawn pod in restricted namespace on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

How to prevent a user to spawn pods in namespace with serviceaccounts that have high privileges but allow them to create namespace ?

For example, I have a cluster with velero in a velero namespace. I want to prevent the user to create pods with the veleroe serviceaccount to prevent the user to create privileged accounts. But I want that the user can create namespace and use serviceaccount with restritected PSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the idiomatic way of enforcing this in Kubernetes is by creating a **dynamic validating admission controller**.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/ https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#validatingadmissionwebhook

I know it could sound a bit complex, but trust me, it's really simple. Eventually, an admission control is simply a webhook endpoint (a piece of code) which can change and/or enforce a certain state on created objects.

So in your case: create a dynamic validating webhook and simply disallow creation of pods that does not match your restrictions, with a corresponding relevant error message.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that. But thanks for the link, it will simply the development.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the service account used by Valero is in the Valero namespace. So if the user don't have RBAC to do anything in Valero namespace it will not be able to use the service account used by Valero. You should define RBAC for users such a way that they only can do CRUD on resources in the intended namespaces and can not do CRUD on resources in other namespaces. When I say resources it also includes service account.

Comment: Yes, but my question is how to define the RBAC so the user can create namespace and do deployments in it without allowing it to create deployment in the system namespaces. What yo are proposing is to prevent the user from creating namespace and only give him permissions on existing namespaces